# SQL Join Issues and displaying wrong value

Tags: sql, join

I am sure this has been answered, but being new to SQL I am not even sure what to look for exactly.

I am looking to join on two tables, based on a unique ID and duration, to return pricing and pricing mis-matches between the two tables. Here's the example:

```
Table1
PK | Item | Duration | Price
1  | 1    | 10       | 1.99
1  | 1    | 15       | 2.99

Table2
PK | Item | Duration | Price
1  | 1    | 10       | 1.99
1  | 1    | 15       | 3.99
```

Now here's my query:

```
SELECT table1.item,
    table1.duration,
    table1.pice,
    table2.item,
    table2.duration,
    table2.pice,
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.item = TABLE 2 item
WHERE table1.duration = table2.duration
```

Here's the issue with my results.

It is matching on item, and duration, but the price is returning the wrong price (it seems to be pulling the first price it finds) i.e it returns:

```
1 | 10 | 1.99 | 1 | 10 | 1.99
1 | 15 | 1.99 | 1 | 15 | 3.99
```

I would expect the second price related to the 15 duration to return 2.99. But it's returning 1.99.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected typos in your code.

```
select table1.item, table1.duration, table1.price,
table2.item, table2.duration, table2.price
from table1 inner
join table2
on table1.item = table2.item
where table1.duration = table2.duration;
```

MSAccess gave the results you expected, not the results you got.
Consider double checking your code.  Or, maybe your SQL implementation is different.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in TSQL (SQL Server) for extra credit.

```
SELECT
     a.[item]
    ,a.[duration]
    ,a.[price]
    ,b.[item]
    ,b.[duration]
    ,b.[price]
    ,a.[price] - b.[price] AS [difference]                      --Difference between two values.
    ,CASE WHEN a.[price] - b.[price] <> 0.00 THEN 'NOT MATCHED' --When difference exists.
          WHEN a.[price] - b.[price] =  0.00 THEN 'MATCHED'     --When difference not exists.
     ELSE NULL END AS [matched]                                 --When records not exists.
FROM        table1 a
INNER JOIN  table2 b ON a.[item]        = b.[item]
AND                      a.[duration]   = b.[duration]
```

The results:

```
item    duration    price   item    duration    price   Difference  Matched
1       10          1.99    1       10          1.99    0.00        MATCHED
1       15          2.99    1       15          3.99    -1.00       NOT MATCHED
```

Then if you only want to pull the records that don't match, then just add this to the bottom:

```
 WHERE a.[price] - b.[price] <> 0.00
```